# Drop if exists in netezza

Tags: if-statement, exists, netezza

I need a command to delete a table if that exists in **NETEZZA**, Something like that:

```
drop table if exists xxx;
```

I have searched and tried many but it didn't work. Can you help me here?

Comment: Why anybody will vote it down?

Answer (score 17):

In `netezza` you can use this syntax:

```
drop table table_name if exists;
```

Comment: This showed up in the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_drop_table.html) starting in 7.2.0

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built-in, but you can create a stored proc which uses the catalog views to check if the table exists before attempting to drop it:

```
create or replace procedure maybe_drop(varchar(128))
    returns boolean
    language nzplsql
as
begin_proc
declare
    oname alias for $1;
    o record;
begin
    select otype into o
    from (
        select 'TABLE' otype from _v_table where tablename = upper(oname)
        union all
        select 'VIEW' otype from _v_view where viewname = upper(oname)
    ) x;

    if found then
        execute immediate 'DROP '||o.otype||' '||oname;
    end if;
end;
end_proc;
```

Comment: Actually i need to have a SQL cmd, should use this directly as a query?

Comment: You can't do it outside of nzplsql, which means you need to create the sproc. Once the sproc is created, you can call in a single statement with `call maybe_drop('my_table');`