# Netezza Create Table if Not Exists

Tags: netezza

When running automated scripts I want to be able to create a table only if it doesn't exist.

Is there a way for `netezza` to evaluate this without throwing an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in [7.2.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_create_table.html) this can be achieved.

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS table_name
( field_name varchar(10))
```

Conversely

[You can can use `if exists` to only drop tables that exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38148944/2682662)

```
drop table table_name if exists;
```